Assistance Needed After System Failure Following Upgrade – Data Preservation Required
I am facing a critical issue after attempting to upgrade my system, and I am seeking urgent help to resolve the problem without losing any data.
Here’s what happened:
I ran the following commands:
sudo apt upgrade
I then started sudo nala upgrade, but canceled it mid-way as it was taking too long.
After canceling the upgrade, I tried to open an application, but it didn’t launch. I then rebooted the system.
Upon rebooting, the system failed to start, and I was dropped into the initramfs shell with the following message:
"Gave up waiting for root file system device. Common problems: - Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline) ... ALERT! UUID does not exist."
I am unsure how to proceed, and my primary concern is not losing any of the data or files on the system.
Here’s what I’ve tried so far:
I ran blkid, but it did not return any results, indicating that the disk may not be detected.
I haven’t run any further commands to avoid causing more issues.
Could you please assist me with resolving this issue, and more importantly, ensuring that all my data remains intact?
